# Google closure compiler with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS giving me empty file

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Command i am using is

```
java -jar closure-compiler-v20181028.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file=out.js input.js
```

my input.js contains only

```
function base() {
    var b='xyz';
                if (b.tagName && 0 == b.tagName.search(this.TAGS_)) {
                    if (b.hasAttribute("href") && void 0 !== self.angular) {
                        var f = b.getAttribute("href");
                        if (f.indexOf("{{") >= 0 && f.indexOf("}}") > 0 && !b.hasAttribute("ng-href"))
                            return b.setAttribute("ng-href", f), void b.removeAttribute("href");
                    }
                    for (var a = 0; a < this.URL_ATTRIBUTES_.length; ++a)
                        if (b.hasAttribute(this.URL_ATTRIBUTES_[a]))
                            return this.updateAttributes_(b, a);
                }
            }
```

i tried with gradle script,  also same result .Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

"...code compiled with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS may not work with uncompiled code unless you take special steps to ensure interoperability. If you do not flag external functions and properties referenced in your code, Closure Compiler will inappropriately rename references in your code, causing mismatches between the names in your code and in the external code."

By "flag" here, they mean "export". For more information see this documentation on the different compilations levels:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels

This blog post:

http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html

And the documentation on exports here:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call `base()`, the code will be removed as it is unreachable.

You'll either want to call it or add an `@export` notation to tell Closure it's needed by other code.

Alternatively, if something is calling `base()` it may not be properly included in your build.

Comment: And if you don't want this behavior, use 'SIMPLE' mode.